# Auto open files in Textpad

Tags: windows-8.1, textpad

Is there a way to configure Textpad to automatically open (previously used) files on start up in Windows 8.1?
Apps like smartclose are not what I'm looking for.
I am very specifically looking for reloading files automatically in Textpad.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can see you need some save state saver application, if you seek on google there are  application called [smartclose](http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/index.htm?http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/smartclose/) i hope that will help you

Answer (score 0):

I have never used TextPad before, and a quick google search didn't seem to turn up anything that could help you. If you are not to attached to TextPad I would suggest checking out [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com), it opens all of the files you last used by default and has a pretty large community so answering your questions or finding add-ons shouldn't be to hard.